# Passport package Installation

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I've just downloaded the laravel 5.8 and I'm trying to install passport, but I'm getting the following composer error:

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - laravel/passport 8.x-dev requires illuminate/encryption ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/encryption[6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version of `Laravel Passport` dropped support for `Laravel 5.8`

> Dropped support for Laravel 5.8 (654cc09)

Install earlier version

```
composer require laravel/passport:7.5.1
```

Reference

[Laravel Passport 8.0 changes](https://github.com/laravel/passport/releases/tag/v8.0.0)

Comment: If it is allowed to comment external URL, you can rerefer the following link  https://dev.to/sandeepbalachandran/api-authentification-with-laravel-5-8-passport-56d7

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your laravel version if possible in `composer.json` set

`"laravel/framework": "6.*",`

and then

`composer install`